# io.grpc.reflection.testing is available under which gradle dependency

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

```
import io.grpc.reflection.testing.AnotherDynamicServiceGrpc;
import io.grpc.reflection.testing.AnotherReflectableServiceGrpc;
import io.grpc.reflection.testing.DynamicReflectionTestDepthTwoProto;
import io.grpc.reflection.testing.DynamicServiceGrpc;
import io.grpc.reflection.testing.ReflectableServiceGrpc;
```

I am trying to import above classes for writing unit tests for server reflection & have added below gradle dependencies -

```
testImplementation group: 'io.grpc', name: 'grpc-testing', version: '1.51.0'
testImplementation group: 'io.grpc', name: 'grpc-protobuf', version: '1.51.0'
testImplementation group: 'io.grpc', name: 'grpc-core', version: '1.51.0'
```

but it is still not showing up. Which gradle dependency is required for them?

Answer (score 0):

Those classes are stubs that are generated at build time from [proto files](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/services/src/test/proto/io/grpc/reflection/testing) in the gRPC [services](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/services) sub-project. This means there is no place you can directly import them from. For your testing you can either define your own test services or you can base them off the ones used by `services`. I recommend using your own proto package names though.